# Assigning a value to label using url Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application, from Controller I'm passing value and text to the HTML view.

Also I want to show another additional field, So I thought not to struggling with the current code and get that data to the label from url.Action method.

I want to know is this possible to do in asp.net ?

Also here is my code so far I did. Need a help to complete the code. Scenario is, if the request has previous settlements, I load that data to the view with the request name and the request Id. Also need to do a modification and show the  previous approver as well

Here is my HTML code.

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <th>
         Settling Request Type
      </th>
      <th>
         Request Id
      </th>
      <th>
         Previously Approved By
      </th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Settlements)
   {
   <tr>
      <td>
         @Html.Label(item.Text.ToString())
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.Label(item.Value)
         @Html.ActionLink("Click to view", "Details", "AppRequests", new { id = @item.Value }, new { target = "_blank" })
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="@Url.Action("PreviousTopApprover", "PendingRequestM", new { id = item.Value })"></a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   }
</table>
```

This is the controller and If it's possible, from here I want to pass the empName to the view and show it.

```
public ActionResult PreviousTopApprover(int ?Id)
{
  if (Id !=null)
  {
   var Approver = (from appProcess in db.ApprovalProcess
                   join appParties in db.ApproveParties on appProcess.Id equals appParties.ApprovalProcess_Id
                   join emp in db.CreateEmployee on appParties.Approver_Id equals emp.Id
                   where appProcess.Req_Id == Id && appParties.Approve_Type == true
                   select new { emp.EmpName }).ToList();

       string empName = Approver.First().EmpName;
       return View();
  }
  else
  {
    return null;
  }
            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't include the data in your view-model, then you'll need to make an AJAX / [FETCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) request to load it.

For example:

```
<td>
    <span data-toggle="fetch" data-url="@Url.Action("PreviousTopApprover", "PendingRequestM", new { id = item.Value })">Loading...</span>
</td>
```

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle='fetch']").forEach(async (el) => {
        const url = el.dataset.url;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorMessage = await response.text();
            console.error(response.status, response.statusText, errorMessage);
            el.innerHTML = "Error loading approver";
            return;
        }
        
        const data = await response.text();
        el.innerHTML = data;
    });
});
</script>
```

You'll also want to change your action:

```
public ActionResult PreviousTopApprover(int ?Id)
{
    if (Id == null) return HttpNotFound();
    
    var approver = (from appProcess in db.ApprovalProcess
                   join appParties in db.ApproveParties on appProcess.Id equals appParties.ApprovalProcess_Id
                   join emp in db.CreateEmployee on appParties.Approver_Id equals emp.Id
                   where appProcess.Req_Id == Id && appParties.Approve_Type == true
                   select new { emp.EmpName })
                   .FirstOrDefault(); 

    if (approver == null) return HttpNotFound();
    
    return Content(approver.EmpName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Small issue,  in the action result it returning the view. Is it okay ? Because I'm getting an error and when I cheeked it on the debug, it searching the view.

Comment: I change it to return content and smoothly working. Thanks again